# How to change the style of a specific section/part of a line chart to dotted/dashed in echarts?

Tags: javascript, charts, echarts

I am trying to achieve something like this using echarts wherein the last part/section of the line chart is dashed, can someone help me figure this out?

Echarts-Line Chart Documentation:
https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/option.html#series-line

[image: Line Chart]

Comment: I'm sure folks would be happy to help once you provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way you can achieve this now is which two series for one line each. One series for solid line, and the other for dashed line.

Comment: Thank you that works, I just added one extra data point to the dashed line series.